# When I select contact name and address from contact list address data not retrieved

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

I need to get contact name and relevant address from contact list in android. I get the contact name and their phone number, but unfortunately unable to get the address details. When I select the contact address, it will return null every time.

I searched the google as well as stackoverflow. But unable to find a solution. When I searched I found that, address details are in another separate table, but I searched that table with id, but didn't return the data from the address table. So please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance,

Please find the code snippet which I used to get the contact details,

```
package com.contact.contacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ListView listView;
    private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        Cursor cur_phone = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (cur_phone.moveToNext()) {

            String name = cur_phone
                    .getString(cur_phone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            String phoneNumber = cur_phone
                    .getString(cur_phone
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            String id = cur_phone.getString(cur_phone
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            System.out.println("Cursor size : contact Name : "+name);
            System.out.println("Cursor size : contact number : "+phoneNumber);
            System.out.println("Cursor size : id : "+id);

        Cursor cursor_address = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor_address.close();

        // get the data package containg the postal information for the contact
        cursor_address = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{ StructuredPostal.STREET,
                StructuredPostal.CITY,
                StructuredPostal.POSTCODE},
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
                    StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id), StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
                null);

        cursor_address.moveToFirst();
        System.out.println("Cursor size : Outside while");

        while (cursor_address.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("Cursor size : Inside while");
            // This while statement is not running

        if(cursor_address != null && cursor_address.moveToFirst())
        {
            if (cursor_address.getCount() > 0) {
                String Street = cursor_address.getString(cursor_address.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.STREET));
                System.out.println("Address : "+Street);
                String Postcode = cursor_address.getString(cursor_address.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                String City = cursor_address.getString(cursor_address.getColumnIndex(StructuredPostal.CITY));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Cursor is : " + cursor_address);
                Log.i("Contact : ", "Cursor :" + cursor_address);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Cursor Null : " + cursor_address);
            Log.i("Contact App : ", "Cursor null" + cursor_address);
        }
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem, Please find the below answer,

```
package com.contact.contacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;
    private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phone = null;
        String poBox = null;
        String street = null;
        String city = null;
        String state = null;
        String postalCode = null;
        String country = null;

        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            //Query for phone 
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null, 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Get the phone number
                        phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    } 
                    pCur.close();

            }

        String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
        String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
        Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null); 
        while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
            poBox = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
            street = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
            city = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
            state = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
            postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
            country = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
            String type = addrCur.getString(
                         addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
        } 
        addrCur.close();

        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phone);

        objContact.setAddressLine1(poBox);
        objContact.setAddressLine2(street);
        objContact.setCity(city);
        objContact.setPostalCode(postalCode);
        objContact.setCountry(country);
        list.add(objContact);

        ContactAdapter objAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ContactActivity.this,
                R.layout.single_contact, list);
        listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

        if (null != list && list.size() != 0) {
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ContactBean>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
                    return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
                }
            });

        } else {
            showToast("No Contact Found!!!");
        }
    }

        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        // Event for item click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> getName(){

        ArrayList<String> mdetail=new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+COLUMN_PERSON_NAME+" from "+TABLE_DETAIL;

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){          
            do {
                mdetail.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME)));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        mCursor.close();
        db.close();
        return mdetail;
    }



if Your data is Sucessfully added in your database just use this code to retreive from database and show in list view like this....


if (!db.exists()) {
         } else {
             mListName=baseManager.getName();
             listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mListName));
         }
```

Comment: Hi Farha, Thanx for the reply, but i want to retrieve contract address from phone's contact list. But your answer is to get data from table. Any way thnx for the reply.

Comment: @AhamedSalik-contract what is this.it is saved in sql database or somewhere else.

Comment: @FarhaSameer786-Sorry Its contact.. Thanks for the reply.. Finally I solve the problem. Please find the answer below